# where is error of "Invalid read of size 4" on the line below the definition of int level

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind, doubly-linked-list

1. the definition of `int level` has `Invalid read of size 4`, and valgrind shows `Memcheck, a memory error detector`.

```c
void sl_set(leapList *head, int *key, int *value) {
    leapList *prev[MAX_SKIPLIST_HEIGHT];
    leapList *curr = head;
    int level = head->height - 1;

    // Find the position where the key is expected
    while (curr != NULL && level >= 0) {
        prev[level] = curr;
        if (curr->next[level] == NULL) {
            -- level;
        } else {
            //int cmp = strcmp(curr->next[level]->key, key);
            //if (cmp == 0) {
            if ((curr->next[level]->key) == key) {
                // Found a match, replace the old value
                free(curr->next[level]->value);
                curr->next[level]->value = value;
                return;
            } else if ((curr->next[level]->key) > key) { // Drop down a level
                -- level;
            } else { // Keep going at this level
                curr = curr->next[level];
            }
        }
    }

    // Didn't find it, we need to insert a new entry
    leapList *new_entry = malloc(sizeof(leapList));
    new_entry->height = grand(head->height);
    new_entry->key = key;
    new_entry->value = value;
    int i;
    // Null out pointers above height
    for (i = MAX_SKIPLIST_HEIGHT - 1; i > new_entry->height; --i) {
        new_entry->next[i] = NULL;
    }
    // Tie in other pointers
    for (i = new_entry->height - 1; i >= 0; -- i) {
        new_entry->next[i] = prev[i]->next[i];
        sOw code as codeprev[i]->next[i] = new_entry;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it article or code ?

Comment: We would need to see the definition of the `leaplist` structure and how you call the `sl_set` function. (You're probably passing a NULL or otherwise invalid pointer.)

Comment: The message from Valgrind should tell you most of what you need to know.  Show it.  If it doesn't include line numbers, recompile and link your code with the `-g` option added.

Answer (score 3):

For `int level = head->height - 1;` to produce an `invalid read of size 4`, there can be only one explanation: the pointer `head` is invalid and you have undefined behavior.

- either `head` is a null pointer, but this should produce a segmentation fault,
- or `head` is uninitialized, but again a segmentation fault would be highly likely,
- or `head` points to a previously freed memory block or an object that has gone out of scope: valgrind detects this condition as the pointer should not be dereferenced but if the memory it points to is readable, the CPU might not generate an error, just meaningless data is read.

Look at the calling code and investigate where `head` is coming from.